# Is the Mario Party 3DS Multiplayer cross-region?

Tags: mario-party-island-tour

I have an UK model, and my friends have an US model, so I'd like to know if I will be able to play with them if I buy the game

Comment: You definitely wont be able to play them on separate devices (like you play his/her game on your 3ds), but I don't know for sure how nintendo deals with multiplayer on regions, though. That might be up to the developers on how they set up the networking.

Comment: Yes, I know I can't play the game itself if I buy the US version - but the download and play depends on the developer... Mario Kart doesn't work cross-region, so I guess Mario Party won't, either =/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your friend/s with the US model/s won't be able to see the game in download play when you host, and neither will you if they host it.

This will occur in all 3DS games with local multiplayer (download play or otherwise).